# Creating a Hierarchical view

Tags: html, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

How do I replicate the hierarchical view that saleforce provides using apex and a visualforce page? I'd like to replicate this in the lookup feature to make it easier to read. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the generated client-side code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's no nested tables there or anything, the easiest way to achieve this would be to use CSS to apply a margin to the rows in question. Most Visualforce tags accept the attribute `styleClass` for which the value is the name of a CSS class to utilise.